# Simple question about infinitesimal generator of uniformly continuous -semigroup

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

I am starting to read the basics of the theory of semigroups of operators, so this questions may be trivial, please forgive my ignorance on the matter.

On Pazy's book it's stated that

$A$ is a bounded operator $\iff$ $A$ generates a uniformly continuous-semigroup $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$.

My question is, since an unbounded operator $A:X\to Y$ may be seen as a bounded operator $A:D(A)\to Y$, I am wondering, if I have for instance the Laplacian operator $\Delta$; this is an unbounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but is it's bounded if we work on the Sobolev space $W^{2,2}$, then:  The uniformly continuous-semigroup generated by $A$ is defined on $D(A)$? Otherwise I don't know how to interpret the statement on Pazy's book.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! I am also new to semigroup theory, and studying it from Pazy. I think, the boundedness of operator A can depend on the space in which we are working. So if $X$ is such that $A$ is bounded, then it will generate a $C_0$-semigroup. But we cannot choose $D(A)$, right? It is defined as all possible elements in $X$ satisfying some condition (right derivative of T at t = 0 exists)

Comment: @P.J. Hi! I think I overlooked the difference between $C_0$-semigroup and "uniformly continuous" semigroup. The latter being stronger (i think).  After a second look I think that the point is: a $C_0$ semigroup is generated by an operator $A$ defined on $D(A)$,   if the operator $A$ is bounded then it generates a uniformly continuous semigroup, not only $C_0$

Comment: @P.J. At this point, I wonder, whether a $C_0$-semigroup is "uniformly continuous" if restricted to $D(A)$.

Comment: your first comment is correct, I checked the book again. As for the second one, could you refer to corollary 2.5 from the book? It says that D(A) is dense in X and A is closed, when A is the inf gen of $C_0$-semigroup T(t). For uniform continuity of the semigroup, we need A to be bounded, and it is not apparent to me how restricting the domain of the semigroup will make A bounded. What do you think?

Comment: @P.J. Indeed I said a stupidity ahahah. I work on stochastic analysis, and the semigroup theory is quite useful for treating SPDEs, but I've never really studied all this things haha

Comment: I work in stochastic calculus as well! :) I am learning this as I go, in order to solve a parabolic SPDE with a non-homogenous term, where A Pazy does not help me, hehe